# Do custom elements respond differently from standard elements; especially regarding DOM lookups?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> *Please advise:  Explain why this is a poor question and not recommended for SO.
>
>   I will gladly succumb to reason and delete accordingly.*

---

```
<!-- HTML5 -->
<someelement>foobar</someelement>
<div class="someelement">foobar</div>
```

I'm not at a place where I can test, but I am generally curious which of the following would be faster and if the result is consistent.  Also, while a person could do a jsperf, I suspect this answer is suitable for SO as there might be good (additional) reasoning into how browsers might implement their rendering/DOM-creation algorithms.  Finally, my apologies if this question has been asked -- I looked and found similar, but could not find.

**Which Vanilla would be faster?** *Perhaps one doesn't work*
`document.getElementsByTagName('someelement')` vs `document.getElementsByClassName('someelement')`

**Which jQuery would be faster?** *(expected to be the same as above)*
`$('someelement')` vs `$('.someelement')`

Comment: The answers differ based on browser/engine version. Feel free to read their source code and report back.

Comment: @epascarello Or do they? HTML5 custom elements are defined as `HTMLUnknownElement` so a feasible solution is that they may behave as any other element.

Comment: I also don't discourage downvotes, but would appreciate reasoning

Comment: @vol7ron Ill be honnest, i did only ready the last 5 lines when I posted my comment, but I retracted it after reading the entire question. But still, I disagree that this question is suitable for SO since you can run the test when you have time and after that the answer will be *"because the algorithme of X is better than the algorithme of Y"*. But well, that's just my opinion.

Comment: And why don't you throw querySelectorAll into the mix? And I am not sure how your comment applies to my comment since I made no comments about element types.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Ahh.  I'll be honest.  I'm actually against jsperf.  There never is a clear answer and it becomes a matter of 100 different tests because someone didn't consider something whereas SO generally has one answer pointing to the correct test.  Also, *if a person just wants to know, it's better to come to SO and have an answer they can find*, instead of thousands of people having to generate their own tests.  **SO is a curation of knowledge; there is one definitive question and one selected answer (and one upvoted answer).*

Comment: @vol7ron I understand your point. jsPerf save all test case, so a quick google search of *"getElementsByTagName vs getElementsByClassName"* give me this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/getelementsbytagname-vs-getelementsbyclass). Then if that doesn't fit your need, you can always edit it and futur user will have access to your edit. That mean people can know the answer without creating a test case. Now, if you want to know why one is faster, well that's the way they are programmed, we can't change that.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon jsPerf is a completely different site.  I don't think you are familiar with the number of community sites that have gone down across the years.  I prefer to have faith in SO.  --- Also, the example you've given doesn't address the main point of my question about ***custom*** elements.

Comment: @epascarello I didn't comment on your comment.  If you want to know about querySelectorAll, pose your own question, but don't hijack mine.

Comment: @vol7ron as stated in my comment, you can adjust the test to your need, so here it is : http://jsperf.com/getelementsbytagname-vs-getelementsbyclass/19. If you want a concret answer. The fact that it is a custom tag change nothing in the algorithm. What's the fastest, depend on browser (check version 1 of the perf). And yes, jsPerf may go down. But now, it is up and you can have the answer to your question with it. If one day, it goes down, now that will be the time to post questions about performance!

Comment: If you're suggesting that people should disregard SO and read the entire documentation, or go test their own solutions until they find them... I don't think that's in the spirit of the site.  One of the many benefits of asking the community at large is to sometimes gain a different perspective, or a clearer understanding of what already exists.  I also don't want SO to depend on other sites, such as jsPerf or jsfiddle.  That is why when answers include things to their, SO has enforced the *must show code* policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/custom-elements-vs-classes

- VanillaJS prefers TagName lookups
  *note: getElementsByClassName may not be supported in some older browsers*
- jQuery prefers ClassName lookups
  *comment: this is somewhat surprising, given the VJS result*

There isn't *too* much difference.  One is faster than the other, but without doing any statistical analysis, the numbers seem relatively close.

---

> Despite the negative attention this question has received, I've finally had a moment to create a quick test — still not sure I set it up correctly.  That said, it was not easy to do so on a mobile device, which was one of the reasons I asked the question in the first place.